# jspm install on heroku server

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, jspm

I'v just deployed my app to Heroku but when I run it in a browser the network tells me it cannot find the system.js file which lives in jspm_packages/system.js

The app works fine locally so I presume heroku is not installing jspm?  Do I need to add a script just for Heroku?

here is the jspm settings in my my package.json

```
"jspm": {
    "directories": {
     "baseURL": "www"
    },
    "dependencies": {
         "google-maps-api": "npm:google-maps-api@^1.1.0",
          "react": "npm:react@^0.14.2",
          "react-dom": "npm:react-dom@^0.14.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
         "babel": "npm:babel-core@^5.8.24",
          "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@^5.8.24",
          "core-js": "npm:core-js@^1.1.4"
      }
 },
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^4.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^3.5.1",
    "jspm": "^0.16.14"
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to submit your jspm packages on heroku. For production run:

```
jspm bundle-sfx lib/main
```

and replace your scripts with:

```
<script src="build.js"></script>
```

(or wherever is your bundled javascript file is)